# Python: multi-dimensional lists - appending one 2D list into another list

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to create a master array/list that takes several two dimensional lists and integrates them into the larger list.

For example I have a `TableA[]` which has `dates` as one array/list and `prices` as another array/list. I have another as TableB[] which has the same. TableA[0][0] has the first date; TableA[0][1] has the first price; TableA[1][0] has the second date, and so on.

I would like to create `BigTabe[]` that has `BigTable[0][0][0] = TableA[0][0]` and `BigTable[1][0][0] = TableB[0][0]`.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That's not a 2d list, its 3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's fairly friendly about this sort of thing and will let you have lists as elements of lists . Here's an example of one way to do it.

`TableA = [['01/01/2000', '$10'], ['02/01/2000', '$11']]`

If you entered this straight into the python interpreter, you'd define TableA as a list with two elements. Both of these elements are also lists. If you then entered in `TableA[0]` you'd get `['01/01/2000', '$10']`. Furthermore, by entering `TableA[0][0]` you'd get `'01/01/2000'` as that's the first element of the first list in TableA.

Extending this further, you can have lists of lists of lists (and so on). First, let's define `TableA` and `TableB`.

`TableA =  [['01/01/2000', '$10'], ['02/01/2000', '$11']]`

`TableB =  [['03/01/2000', '$13'], ['04/01/2000', '$14']]`

Now we can simply define `BigTable` as having `TableA` and `TableB` as its elements.

`BigTable = [TableA, TableB]`

Now, `BigTable[0]` is just `TableA` so `BigTable[0][0][0]` will be the same as `TableA[0][0]`

If at some point down the line you realise that you want `BigTable` to have more lists in it, say a `TableC` or `TableD`. Just use the append function.

`BigTable.append(TableC)`

By the way, you'll probably want to have prices and dates expressed as numbers rather than strings, but it's easier to follow the example this way.

Comment: Hi Orca - I just wanted to finally follow up and let you know that your answer was very helpful! I really appreciate that you took the time to explain how to append lists within lists. I use BigTable.Append() all the time now. Thanks again!
(It won't yet let me upvote the explanation, but as soon as I'm able to, I will.)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.